# False proof: finding the integral $\int 4\sin^4x \, dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I know there is something wrong with my work below, but I'm not sure what. I believe my answer is missing a (3/2)x, but after going through my work three or four times I cannot find the mistake for the life of me. (Yes, I know there is an alternate way of solving the integral, but I'm more interested on finding what I did wrong than finding the correct solution at this point). Thanks for the help.

\begin{align*}
& \int 4\sin^4x \, dx & \\
&= \int 4\sin^2x\left(1-\cos^2x \right) dx & \\
&= \int \left( 4\sin^2x - 4\sin^2x\cos^2x \right) dx & \\
&= \int \left( 4\sin^2x - \sin^22x \right) dx & \\
&= -4 \int \frac{\cos(2x) - 1}{2} \, dx + 4 \int \frac{\cos(4x) - 1}{2} \, dx \\
&= -2\left[ 0.5\sin2x - x \right] + 2\left[ 0.25\sin4x - x \right] + C \\
&= -\sin2x + 2x + 0.5\sin4x - 2x + C \\
&= -\sin2x + 0.5\sin4x + C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the step
$$\int (4 \sin^2 x - \sin^2 2x) \, dx = -4 \int \frac{\cos 2x - 1}{2} \, dx + \color{red}{4} \int \frac{\cos 4x - 1}{2} \, dx.$$

You have included an extra factor of $4$.

Comment: I never realized how similar mathematics was to programming. I miss such a tiny, obvious in hindsight thing like this and it completely screws up my answer. Even though it's a little embarrassing to even have to come here for it to resolved this simply, thank you very much for your response.